# Cannot see CPU temperature on Intel Extreme Tuning Utility

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu, temperature, intel-core-i7

I recently bought a laptop for gaming with Windows. After have seen some video tutorial I started dealing with Intel Extreme Tuning Utility to decrease CPU performance while not playing in order to decrease temperature and noise. This is the first time in my life that I deal with overclocking softwares so I'm quite newbie.

Despite video tutorials:

1. I noticed that in the lower graph actually I cannot see the CPU features and I've got "Package Temperature 0°C" and "Max Core Frequency 0.00 GHz" and that's strange because it should be some values, furthermore,
2. While decreasing the Core Voltage Offset, if less than -180V, Windows goes in Blue Screen.
3. Each time I open Intel Extreme Tuning Utility a popup says me something like "Download the latest version of the program from the Microsoft store" but actually I cannot find anything and I already have the latest version (6.4.1.23).

Can someone pelase explain me theese behaviours?

My Laptop:
TUXEDO P95_HP (U3E1)
Windows 10 Pro N 64-bit
Intel Core i7 7700HQ @ 2.80GHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ramhound says the Intel Core i7 7700HQ is not fully supported by XTU software but I can confirm that decreasing the `Core Voltage Offset` something changed and either the temperature and noise got pretty lowered (reduced by -5°C in total) while using my laptop for routine.

Probably another good path on Windows that I had followed is to deal with the `CPU power saver options` on the `Control Panel` lowering the percentage of the minimum CPU performance.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain me these behaviors?

The utility does not support your processor.

> I noticed that in the lower graph actually I cannot see the CPU features and I've got "Package Temperature 0°C" and "Max Core Frequency 0.00 GHz" and that's strange because it should be some values, furthermore, While decreasing the Core Voltage Offset, if less than -180V, Windows goes in Blue Screen.

You cannot overclock or underclock your processor.  While you can change the voltage on the processor, that would have to be done within the UEFI settings, and even then it wouldn't result in a performance increase.  As for the BSOD, the voltage changes you are making, are resulting in an unstable system.

> Each time I open Intel Extreme Tuning Utility a popup says me something like "Download the latest version of the program from the Microsoft store" but actually I cannot find anything and I already have the latest version (6.4.1.23).

You should download the Intel Extreme Tuning Utility directly from Intel.

[Intel® Extreme Tuning Utility (Intel® XTU)](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24075/Intel-Extreme-Tuning-Utility-Intel-XTU-)

Comment: Hi @Ramhound and thankyou for your clear reply. I actually downloaded XTU from the same link you suggested. Anyway, probably I was not clear on saying that my goal is to speed-down processor while not gaming (og game works well and don't need to get it stronger), but I guess the unstability could occurr even with undervoltage. Based on your experience, what do you suggest to achieve my goal?

Comment: @grimi You won’t be able to underclock this particular processor.

Comment: I've just asked to a colleague that has the same 7700HQ and uses XTU. He says something like: "You can undervolt that but not too much... just make some try until you get BSOD no more or you may try to find something else" about the unsigned temperature he says: "It may be chipset driver fault since speccy can recognize that" (because it does, I didn't mentioned). Anyway, can you suggest me any other tool that can make underclocking even on 7700HQ? If not, I'll proceed once home to make some try with XTU again since I recognize some temperature decreasement. Thanks 1000!

Comment: There isn’t another tool.  You can chnage the voltage within the UEFI settings as I stated in my answer

Comment: Ok I'll do as you said. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That utility is for a narrow set of Desktop processors, and none of them are mobile processors. So it will not work for your laptop.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I used the link Ramhound posted as the source

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24075/Intel-Extreme-Tuning-Utility-Intel-XTU-

Comment: You don’t have to give me credit.  It’s not my link.  I didn’t bother listening the processors that were supported since the list will change, and even when that happens the mobile processor the author has won’t be supported

Answer (score 0):

Off-Topic but you may be able to get the CPU temperature with a simple Batch Script:

echo off

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH 
MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature /value') do 
set /a "HunDegCel=(%%~A*10)-27315"
echo %HunDegCel:~0,-2%.%HunDegCel:~-2% Degrees Celsius
```

Some hardware may not support it, but for me and 2 others it does.